# provide alternate page template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have made a WordPress plugin that handles ajax post.

Whenever I post using ajax to the same page or plugin I need only certain amount of data being returned and not all the header and footer that default page template has.

Whenever I get response from the server after ajax post I need to append the data to some div. So how can I use different page templates at runtime: one when the plugin page is loaded and another after the response/data from the server is recieved?

Page template structure:

```
<?php
 /**
    Template Name: Page
 */
    //get header
    //get content
    //get footer ?>
```

Blank page template structure:

```
<?php
 /**
    Template Name: blank page
 */
    //get content
?>
```

Now during ajax response from server i want to use blank page template. How do i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress already has support for AJAX-calls, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Basically you bind a function to an action with the special prefix `wp_ajax_`:

```PHP
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

The URL for this is then already defined by WordPress, you only have to use it:

```js
var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'whatever': 1234
};

// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
```

Using this method will ensure that you get a clean AJAX response, without parts of the theme.

Details can be found in the WordPress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side